# Is it possible to call a css class in angular after a time delay of 4 seconds?

Tags: angular

I’m trying to display a toast. 
If there are two incidents. One should be displayed after another. Both of them use the same class. But I need to call them one after the other. So I would like to know if it’s possible to call a css class again after 4 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you can do here is define the class in the component like:

```
cls: string = 'initialClassName';
```

You can use 'setTimeout' to change the class name after certain time:

```
  ngOnInit() {
        setTimeout( () => {
         this.cls = 'afterClassName'
       }, 4000);
  }
```

In the template use ngClass to include the dynamic class name:

```
  <div [ngClass]="cls"></div>
```